# Get Method is getting called but I have given POST method in my form

Tags: javascript, java, servlets

I am calling a POST method from JSP but by default, GET is getting called in servlet and none of the post parameters are coming in the request.

I have checked all the existing questions but none of them is solving my problem as I am submitting the form from the javascript method.

Same JSP, js and java code is working fine in my live environment.

So I am not able to understand, is it some version issue or what. Still, I'm putting my code below if anything can be changed to make it work.

I have tried putting the encoding tag in form enctype as in one solution it is given that encoding can be one issue sometimes but didn't work.

JSP Code:

```
 //web.xml configuration is done properly
    <form action="FileDownloadServlet" method="POST" id="fDownload">
        <input type="hidden" name="fileId" id="fileId"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="status1" id="status1"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="volume1" id="volume1"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="fileType" id="fileType" value="summaryPDF"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="documentType" id="documentType" value="SO"/>
    </form>
```

JS Code is below:

```
//It is fetching the below values from a form on the current page storing values in hidden and it is printing these values in js properly.


    var docID = dwr.util.getValue("docId");
        var status = dwr.util.getValue("status");
        var volume = dwr.util.getValue("volume");
        jq('#fileId').val(docID);
        jq('#status1').val(status);
        jq('#volume1').val(volume);
        document.forms[0].action = "FileDownloadServlet";
        document.forms[0].submit();
```

Servlet Code:

```
                         //In form we gave POST as form method but still output is calling doGet
          @Override
            protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                    throws ServletException, IOException {
                System.out.println("calling doGet");
                processRequest(request, response);
            }

            @Override
            protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                    throws ServletException, IOException {
                     System.out.println("calling doPost");
                processRequest(request, response);
            }
```

It is calling GET method every single time.

Comment: can't reproduce - your code works fine - is the above form the only, or first, form in the page? if so, why are you setting `action` to the same value as it already is? try using `document.forms.fDownload` instead of `document.forms[0]` - see if that "fixes" your error

Comment: I have used same kind of  code in my application at various places and it stopped working all at once. I have tried everything but it is not working. what others factors can be there that it will call GET instead of POST.

Comment: Are you sure that `document.forms[0]` is the `#fDownload` form ?

Comment: `it stopped working all at once` perhaps there's another form? what is `document.forms.length`

Comment: yes I have only one form in the JSP page

Comment: what is `document.forms.length`? does using `document.forms.fDownload` instead of `document.forms[0]` help?

Comment: so ... what was `document.forms.length` ... bet it was > 1

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Jaromanda X in comments.
I did below changes and now it is working fine.

```
document.forms.formID.action = "FileDownloadServlet";
document.forms.formID.submit();
```